# Axios runs a query automatically to my root directory

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am doing a project in Vue 2 with Nuxt and Every time you run a query with Axios, apart from running an additional query to the razis directory, I don't know how to avoid it, I'm consulting an Api project, which has no root directory but all are contained by /api

AxiosApi.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { api_url } from '../constants/config'
export default () => {
    const options = {
        baseURL: hefesto_api_url,
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('tokenLogin')
        }  
    };
    const instance = axios.create(options);
    return instance;
};
```

Example:

```
import axiosApi from "../../services/axiosApi.js"; 
async getUser({ commit }, payload){

    await axiosApi().get(`/users/admin/find-by-token/${ payload.token }`).then( (result) => {

        const user_result = result.data;
        console.log(user_result);

    }).catch( (error) => {

        const user_error = error.response.data;

        commit('setNotification', { type: 'error', message: user_error.message });
    });
},
```

Result: [Detail of the query that Axios performs automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elV4n.png)

Comment: What does `localStorage.getItem` do? Is it making the extra request?

Comment: No, it only brings the localstorage token from the browser

Comment: How is  localstorage in the browser populated if there hasn't been a connection to the server? Can you confirm that the 'wrong' request doesn't happen with the import by commenting out the `axiosApi().get` call?

Comment: 1- The localstorage is filled when you log in to the application


2- If I comment it, it doesn't run, that's why I don't know, because an additional query to the one I'm doing is executed